# Does there exist a distribution defined on $\mathbb{R}$ which is $1/x$ over $(-\infty,0)$ and $2/x$ over $(0,+\infty)$?

Tags: distribution-theory

Does there exist  a distribution defined on $\mathbb{R}$ which is $1/x$ over $(-\infty,0)$ and $2/x$ over $(0,+\infty)$?
I think yes but i am not very sure:
Let $u_1(\phi)$ be $2\int_0^{+\infty}(\frac{\phi(x)-\phi(0)}{x})dx$ and $u_2(\phi)$ be $\int_{-\infty}^{0}(\frac{\phi(x)-\phi(0)}{x})dx$ for every test function $\phi$.
Does $u_1+u_2$ works?
I don't understand if it must satisfy some "gluing" conditions.
(And the problem is which are all homogeneous distributions of order a negative integer over $\mathbb{R}$?)

Comment: you should modify your integrals to make them convergent - subtract $\phi(0)$ only in a bounded interval (and then it will work as you intend)

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand why they don't converge ($\phi$ has compact support)

Comment: but $\phi(x)-\phi(0)$ does not have compact support, so the integral diverges

Comment: After the fix indicated by user8268, to be done on each side, the $u_1+u_2$ is indeed a distribution which solves the problem. There is no gluing to worry about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By requiring conditions only on $(0,\infty)$ and on $(-\infty,0)$, there is no uniqueness of the distribution you are looking for since one can add any distribution of the form $c\,\delta_0^{(n)}$. First, there is no **homogeneous distribution** with the constraints you are requiring (The residue of the function in $0$ should be $0$ for that to be possible, as you can find in a good course on distribution theory).

The way I like to find a singular distribution is by looking at the derivative of a $L^1_{\mathrm{loc}}$ function. Here, we can take for example $f=g'$ with
$$
g(x) = (1+H(x))\ln(|x|)
$$
where $H(x) = \mathbf{1}_{\mathbb R_+}$, so that in the classical sense, $f(x) = g'(x) = 1/x$ when $x< 0$ and $f(x) = 2/x$ when $x>0$. Now we can do the derivative in the sense of distributions: for $\varphi\in C^\infty_c$,
$$
\begin{align*}
\langle f,\varphi\rangle = -\langle g,\varphi'\rangle &= -\int_{\mathbb R} (1+H(x))\ln(|x|)\, \varphi'(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
\\
&= -2\int_0^\infty \ln(x)\, \varphi'(x)\,\mathrm{d}x - \int_{-\infty}^0 \ln(-x)\, \varphi'(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}
$$
For the first integral we have (integrating by parts and using the fact that $\ln(1)=0$)
$$
\begin{align*}
-\int_0^\infty \ln(x)\, \varphi'(x)\,\mathrm{d}x &= -\int_0^1\ln(x)\, (\varphi(x)-\varphi(0))'\,\mathrm{d}x - \int_1^\infty \ln(x)\, \varphi'(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
\\
&= \int_0^1  \frac{\varphi(x)-\varphi(0)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x + \int_1^\infty \frac{\varphi(x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x
\\
&= \int_0^\infty  \frac{\varphi(x)-\varphi(0)\,\mathbf{1}_{[0,1]}(x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}
$$
and with a similar computation for the second integral, we get a the end
$$
\begin{align*}
\langle f,\varphi\rangle = \int_{-\infty}^0 \frac{\varphi(x)-\varphi(0)\,\mathbf{1}_{[-1,0]}(x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x + 2\int_0^\infty  \frac{\varphi(x)-\varphi(0)\,\mathbf{1}_{[0,1]}(x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}
$$

---

**Remark:** If we want all the solutions, then we can take any distribution of the form $f(x) + \sum_n c_n\,\delta_0^{(n)}$. Remark in particular that taking $f(x) + c\delta_0$ is equivalent to replacing $\mathbf{1}_{[0,1]}$ by $\mathbf{1}_{[0,R]}$ for some $R$ in the above integral, and is also equivalent to replace $g$ by another antiderivative $g+c H(x)$. So my choice here corresponds to taking $c=0$.

Comment: Yes very interesting ty, but i still can't understan why the distributional derivative of log(x) (as an $L_{loc}^1$ function over $[0,+\infty)$) is not homogeneous of degree -1. I think that a a distribution is homogeneous of degree $\alpha$ iff it satisfies the equation $xu^{'}-\alpha u =0$ and i can't interpret your consideration on residue. Can you add some details please (where $\alpha$ is complex or real and $u$ is a distribution).

Comment: Derivatives of homogeneous distributions are homogeneous, but it does not apply here since $\ln$ is not homogeneous, since
$$
\ln(|\lambda x|) = \ln(|\lambda|) + \ln(|x|)
$$

Comment: To see that $f$ is not homogeneous we can use your equation, this gives
$$
\langle x\, f',\varphi\rangle = - \langle f,\varphi\rangle - \langle f,x \,\varphi'\rangle
$$
and since $(x\,\varphi')(0)=0$, we get
$$
-\langle f,x \,\varphi'\rangle = -\int_{-\infty}^0 \varphi' -2\int_0^\infty \varphi' = \varphi(0)
$$
therefore
$$
x\,f' + f = \delta_0
$$
In some sense, the distributions can see what is happening at the singularity at $x=0$. Here, you have a "jump" of homogeneity when you go from $x<0$ to $x>0$.

The constant $1$ in front of the Dirac delta is exactly the residue.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other good answwers, the issue of *homogeneity* is of some interest.

Neither of the two functions $1/x$, $1/|x|$ is locally $L^1$ near $0$, so some variant of them must be defined indirectly, for example, by meromorphic continuation, or by other "regularization".

The {\it odd} distribution defined by meromorphic continuation of $\mathrm{sgn}(x)/|x|^s$ is holomorphic at $s=1$, and the value is (a constant multiple of) the Cauchy Principal Value integral $\varphi\to P.V. \int_{\mathbb R} {\varphi(x)\over x}\,dx$. The meromorphic cont'n of the {\it even} distribution $1/|x|^s$ has a simple pole at $s=1$, with residue (some constant multiple of) Dirac's $\delta$.

Thus, in addition to degree of (positive-) homogeneity (possibly gauged by eigenvalues of the Euler operator $x{\partial\over \partial x}$, we should also pay attention to {\it parity}, under the action of $\pm 1$. Thus, The function $u(x)$ that is $1/x$ for $x>0$ and $0$ for $x<0$ is a non-trivial linear combination of *both*...

This *suggests* that with $v(x)=\log |x|$ for $x>0$ and $0$ for $x<0$ might fail to be positive-homogeneous, and indeed this is the case. In contrast, the Principal Value functional *is* homogeneous of the expected degree (however we choose to normalize things). But the failure of the *formula* may be (but happens not to be, here) misleading. Namely, the functional (integrate-against) $1/|x|$ on the closed subspace of test functions (e.g.) vanishing to infinite order at $0$ need not be given by the same formula. (And if we forget requirements of parity and homogeneity, Hahn-Banach of course gives extensions...)

We claim that the *only* even-parity, positive-homogeneous-degree $-1$ distribution $u$ is (up to constant multiples) $\delta$. In particular, the support of such $u$ must be $0$, and it cannot be (any non-zero constant multiple of) $1/|x|$ away from $0$. To see this, let $f$ be a test function that is *even*, identically $1$ on $[-1,1]$, identically $0$ off $[-2,2]$, and monotonically decreases from $1$ to $0$ on $[1,2]$ and oppositely on $[-2,-1]$. By construction, $f(x)-f(2x)$ is identically $0$ near $0$, so has support away from $0$. Since $\mathbb R^\times$ is transitive on the punctured real line, uniqueness of invariant functionals shows that the restriction of $u$ to the space $X$ of test functions vanishing to infinite order at $0$ must be a constant multiple $c/|x|$ of (integration against) $1/|x|$. Thus,
$$
0 \;=\; u(x \to f(x)-f(2x)) \;=\; c\int_{\mathbb R} {f(x)-f(2x)\over |x|}\;dx
$$
The integrand is non-negative everywhere, and strictly positive on a set of positive measure. Thus, the integral itself is non-zero. Hence, the constant $c$ must be $0$.

In particular, although $\log|x|$ and $\mathrm{sgn}\cdot \log|x|$ are locally $L^1$ near $0$, and so have distributional derivatives computed correctly away from $0$ as $1/|x|$ and $1/x$, in the first case that derivative is *not* homogeneous. (In the latter, it is, being the principal value distribution.)

That is, whatever regularization we do perform on integrate-against-$1/|x|$ (unless we produce the $0$ functional), the outcome cannot possibly be homogeneous.

EDIT: the Euler equation is more-or-less equivalent to "positive" homogeneity, meaning homogeneity (however we normalize it) only for *positive* dilations. That is, we are only talking about the action of *positive* real numbers on functions and distributions. To include the action of negative real numbers (after the action of positive ones is specified), we only need to specify the action of $\pm 1$, that is, parity. The Euler differential equation does not touch parity...

The approach through meromorphic continuation of families is not strictly necessary to understand the existence and uniqueness here... though I do think in the long run it is very beneficial. Perhaps steep prerequisites, yes. "Vector-valued integrals" and "vector-valued holomorphic functions" (after Schwartz and Grothendieck). I do treat these things in various of my notes, but, yes, while it's less crazy than some other things, it's perhaps not suitable for absolute beginners looking at PDE involving distributions.

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand your answer, are $u_1$ and $u_2$ distributions? (by subtracting $\phi(0)$ the pole should be absorbed)

Comment: @yoyo, I hope my amplification is useful to you.

Comment: Yes is very useful even if i can't understand all of your datails, i am not used to the language, sorry.. The point is that i don't fully understand if the Euler equation $xu{'}-\lambda x=0$ is necessary and sufficent to have a homogenous distribution, where is that the parity comes in to play? I mean, i can't understand what are you referring about when you say a meromorphic continuation which is holomorphic in $s=1$ or has a pole in $s=1$... If you can add more datails it would be great thanks

Comment: Good point about delta being the only homogeneous example. Related https://mathoverflow.net/questions/273296/no-kernel-of-the-form-lvert-x-y-rvert-1-on-tempered-distributions/273301#273301

Answer (score 1):

Let $u:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by
$$
u(x) = \begin{cases}
\ln |x| & (x<0) \\
0 & (x=0) \\
2\ln |x| & (x>0)
\end{cases}
$$
This function is locally integrable, so it defines a distribution by integration, and its derivative, also a distribution, satisfies
$$
u'(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{x} & (x<0) \\
\frac{2}{x} & (x>0)
\end{cases}
$$